# Angular Modal not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a very simple modal defined as:

```
var modelTemplate = '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">Test</h3></div><div class="modal-body">Selected</div><div class="modal-footer"></div>';
```

and I'm showing it as:

```
$scope.showAbout = function (){
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({template: modelTemplate});
}
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/noor/Documents/files/developlement/k7/android/WorldCup2014/template/modal/backdrop.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/noor/Documents/files/developlement/k7/android/WorldCup2014/template/modal/window.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. 
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Fmodal%2Fbackdrop.html
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Fmodal%2Fwindow.html
```

Comment: What library for UI you use? ui.bootstrap?

Comment: yes, I'm using ui.bootsrap

Comment: Try to download library again, with included templates

Comment: I think the problem is that you opened the page as a file (e.g. `file:///home/noor/.../index.html`). Open the page from a server running on localhost (e.g. node.js or apache) or disable your browser's same origin policy (not recommended)

Comment: this app will be finally a mobile app which will be build using cordova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not enough details in the question so I can't be sure but I *think* that you are including wrong files from the angular-ui/bootstrap distribution. Keep in mind that while several files are distributed you need to include *only one* of them. The exact file to include depends on the use case but most of the time you want to include `ui-bootstrap-tpls-[version].min.js`.

Different types of distributed files are described here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files

and the installation instructions are available here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#installation

In short - make sure that you are including the distribution file with embedded templates. If it still doesn't work post a plunk with a live reproduce scenario.

Comment: yes, you were right, I was wrongly including the file